# Botconnector not working for a self signed nodejs bot

Tags: botframework, botconnector

I created a simple bot. Self signed the ssl cert. Apparently that does not work for bot connector . I get following error form the bot, after several seconds.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadCertificate",
        "message": "An error occurred while sending the request. The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. ",
        "statusCode": 500
    }
}
```

Does that mean self signed certificates are out of question for the bot? Any work around this problem?

Comment: I think you need a legitimate certificate. If you host it as an App Service in Azure, you can get this for free without a custom domain (costs money with a custom domain).

Comment: yes, i will have to try that out. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, self-signed certs are not supported.

If you use HTTPS, you must have a properly chained cert. The Bot Connector uses standard server certificate validation to make sure your site is what it claims to be. Put another way, if you point a browser to your bot and your browser thinks the cert is legit, the Bot Connector likely will, too. If your browser doesn't like it, the Bot Connector probably won't either.

This is true for bots implemented in all languages.

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue with a properly chained cert. Any particular authorities that BC doesn't like?

Comment: It turns out that my issue is that Bot Framework only supports TLS 1.0 (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38022581/1110820).

Comment: So Microsoft, full commited to Bots, send a message to developpers on earth not to use their framework ? Putting a real SSL certificate for an HelloBot is just a pain in the ass