# "Create a new bot" button greyed out

Tags: skype, botframework

I decided to try moving my working Skype bot from the Skype API to the Microsoft Bot Framework. Once the [SSL connection was working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997948/cant-establish-ssl-tls-secure-channel-with-signed-cert#comment63964513_38022581), I tested sending a message to my actual application from Skype itself. Unfortunately, I didn't notice the part where I'm [supposed to use the dev web Skype app](http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/update/#update-your-bot-to-use-the-new-v3-api); so, my application was receiving messages in the structure defined by the Skype API. It was not receiving messages from the bot framework. So, I deleted the Skype bot.

Now, I've realized that the MBF doesn't seem to actually... do anything? I'm still supposed to create a Skype bot, in addition to having an MBF bot?

At any rate, I'm trying to recreate the Skype bot, but the "Create a new bot" button is greyed out:

[image: 3]

Right below that is a link that seems to imply that I will be creating the bot on the MBF.  But, as mentioned above, the MBF wants me to create a Skype bot:

[image: 4]

Ahhhhhh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are creating a brand new bot start here
  https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new.   With the V3 release, creating a bot in the Bot Framework will automatically provision the bot in Skype.  (No longer any need to copy keys, etc.)   You can always disable the Skype channel it if you choose not to release your bot on Skype.
- If you are adding Skype to a bot you created before the V3 release you will need to go through the old manual Skype provisioning process (what you are showing in your 2nd screen shot)

Comment: Huh, yeah, the version 3 option wasn't present earlier today, but it is now. That seems to be working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot of the Bot Framework configuration page you showed above looks out of date. Please could you try clearing the cache with Ctrl-F5 and creating a new Bot Framework bot. You should not need to use the Skype Bot Portal at all.

Comment: Yeah, the new options are there now. Thanks.